# How to find similar words which might have multiple spaces from descriptions with scores based on found keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find all rows that contain similar words in a SQL Server table.

Let's say my table is called TableA and it has the following structure:

```
ID   State            Description
1     LA        Good quality products and Canadian environment acts
2     NY        Race diversity
3     WA        We are too diverse a group 
4     LA        Environmental problem solution
5     LA        Good environment
```

I also have another table called TableB that has a list of words that I want to search for:

```
Word_A                 Word_B                           Word_C

good quality     canadian environment acts              group
divers           problem solution
environment      Race
we
too
```

What I want to do is retrieve all rows from TableA that contain any of the words in TableB, along with the specific keyword(s) found in each row with scores based on how many keywords there are for each Word_A(10),B(5),C(0.1) like this:

```
ID State        Description                                             keywords_A            Keywords_B                    Keywords_C        Score
1     LA        Good quality products and Canadian environment acts     good quality          canadian environment acts                       15
2     NY        Race diversity                                                                Race                                            5
3     WA        We are too diverse a group                              We, diversity, too                                  group             30.1
4     LA        Environmental problem solution                          Envrionmental         problem solution                                15
5     LA        Good environment                                        environment                                                          10
```

What I've tried is

```
WITH KeywordMatches AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Description, value AS keyword
    FROM (select top 100000 * from TableA) a
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Description, ' ')
),
KeywordScores AS (
    SELECT ID, 
           STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ColAKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN ColAKeyword END, ', ') AS keywords_A,
           STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ColBKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN ColBKeyword END, ', ') AS keywords_B,
           STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN ColCKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN ColCKeyword END, ', ') AS keywords_C,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColAKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) AS ColAScore,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColBKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) AS ColBScore,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColCKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 0.1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColCScore
    FROM (
        SELECT ID,
               CASE
                WHEN LOWER(keyword) LIKE LOWER(k.[Word_A]) + '%' THEN keyword
                when [Word_A] like '% %' 
                then substring(ContentDescription, 
                               charindex(lower([Word_A]), lower(Description)), 
                               len([ColA]))
               END AS ColAKeyword,
               CASE
                WHEN LOWER(keyword) LIKE LOWER(k.[Word_B]) + '%' THEN keyword
        when [Word_B] like '% %' 
                then substring(Description, 
                               charindex(lower([Word_B]), lower(Description)), 
                               len([ColB]))
               END AS ColBKeyword,
           CASE 
                WHEN LOWER(keyword) LIKE LOWER(k.[Word_C]) + '%' THEN keyword
                when [Word_C] like '% %' 
                then substring(Description, 
                               charindex(lower([Word_C]), lower(Description)), 
                               len([ColC]))
               END AS ColCKeyword
        FROM KeywordMatches km
        JOIN TableB k 
            ON  km.Description LIKE '%' + k.[Word_A] + '%'
            OR  km.Description LIKE '%' + k.[Word_B] + '%'
            OR  km.Description LIKE '%' + k.[Word_C] + '%'
    ) v
    WHERE (ColAKeyword IS NOT NULL OR ColBKeyword IS NOT NULL OR ColCKeyword IS NOT NULL OR ColDKeyword IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY ID
) 

SELECT distinct ks.ID, q.State, Description,
       replace(replace(ks.keywords_A,',,',','),'.,',',') as keywords_A,
       replace(replace(ks.keywords_B,',,',','),'.,',',') as keywords_B,
       replace(replace(ks.keywords_C,',,',','),'.,',',') as keywords_C,
       (ks.ColAScore + ks.ColBScore + ks.ColCScore) AS Score
FROM KeywordScores ks
JOIN TableA q ON ks.ID = q.ID
```

For keywords that do not have 'space' like (diversity, We, too) captured correctly, but keywords that have 'space' such as (Canadian environment act, problem solution) are not captured correctly.

Do you have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: for that you should use Full Text searches https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16 and if that isn't fast enough you can look at elastic search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `PATINDEX` instead of `SUBSTRING`

```
WITH KeywordMatches AS (
    SELECT ID, 
           CASE 
               WHEN PATINDEX('%' + LOWER(k.WordA) + '%', LOWER(q.Description)) > 0 THEN k.WordA 
           END AS ColAKeyword,
           CASE 
               WHEN PATINDEX('%' + LOWER(k.WordB) + '%', LOWER(q.Description)) > 0 THEN k.WordB 
           END AS ColBKeyword,
           CASE 
               WHEN PATINDEX('%' + LOWER(k.WordC) + '%', LOWER(q.Description)) > 0 THEN k.ColC 
           END AS ColCKeyword
    FROM TableA q
    JOIN TableB AS k
        ON q.Description LIKE '%' + k.WordA + '%'
            OR q.Description LIKE '%' + k.WordB + '%'
            OR q.Description LIKE '%' + k.WordC + '%'
    WHERE
        k.WordA IS NOT NULL
        OR k.WordB IS NOT NULL
        OR k.WordC IS NOT NULL
        OR k.WordD IS NOT NULL
)
, KeywordScores AS (
    SELECT ID, 
           STUFF((
               SELECT ', ' + ColAKeyword
               FROM KeywordMatches innerKM
               WHERE innerKM.ID = km.ID AND ColAKeyword IS NOT NULL
               FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') AS KeywordsA,
           STUFF((
               SELECT ', ' + ColBKeyword
               FROM KeywordMatches innerKM
               WHERE innerKM.ID = km.ID AND ColBKeyword IS NOT NULL
               FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') AS KeywordsB,
           STUFF((
               SELECT ', ' + ColCKeyword
               FROM KeywordMatches innerKM
               WHERE innerKM.ID = km.ID AND ColCKeyword IS NOT NULL
               FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') AS KeywordsC,
           STUFF((
               SELECT ', ' + ColDKeyword
               FROM KeywordMatches innerKM
               WHERE innerKM.ID = km.ID AND ColDKeyword IS NOT NULL
               FOR XML PATH('')
           ), 1, 2, '') AS Captured_Words_ColD,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColAKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) AS ColAScore,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColBKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) AS ColBScore,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ColCKeyword IS NOT NULL THEN 0.1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColCScore
    FROM KeywordMatches km
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT DISTINCT q.ID, 
                q.State,  
                q.Description,
                (ks.ColAScore + ks.ColBScore + ks.ColCScore) AS Score
FROM TableA q
JOIN KeywordScores ks ON q.ID = ks.ID;
```